Power Automate - Attach file to email from URL stored in SharePoint list which regards a SharePoint file
I'm working on a flow that sends automatic email with ticket details when "Status" of an item is changed in MS Lists.
Then the flow should take one of the URLs (which links against a file in SharePoint) available in the corresponding column field in MS Lists which had the status changed to attach a file (Excel, Word or PDF) as attachment (not the URL) in the email to be sent through Outlook.
Can anyone help me which steps and variables I should adopt to:
1 - take from item ID the corresponding URL under specified column in MS Lists
2 - Get file name
3 - Get file content
So then it can be attached in "Send an email (v2)?
NOTE: Flow was developed in Power Automate MS 365 environment not desktop.
Many thanks in advance.
Currently I'm not getting any right steps for the goal here...


Get files (properties only), where you can write your query in the 'Filter query' field
Get file content. The 'File identifier' attribute comes from the previous step
in the 'Send an email (V2)' step, you can use the outputs of these steps in the attachments fields


Update, I've found a better solution:

Compose: maybe just a bug, but the two query in the next actions have different logic: the metadata querying one has a server relative url, the content querying one needs absolute url. You said, that you have absolute url, so you need to substring it (and if you have a whitespace in the Documents library name, you need to replace it):


replace(substring(triggerOutputs()?['body/hyperlink'],47),'%20',' ')

(I know that my relative url starts at the 47th character)

Get file metadata using path


@outputs('Compose')


Get file content using path


@triggerOutputs()?['body/hyperlink']


Send an Email (v2)
"emailMessage/Attachments": [
{
"Name": "@outputs('Get_file_metadata_using_path')?['body/Name']",
"ContentBytes": "@body('Get_file_content_using_path')"
}
]



Hi Farkas. Thanks for your orientation above.
On the Get files (properties only), can you give me a hint how I could write the query in the 'Filter query' field as I believe it should look for the item ID when and item or file is modified, and then under the column called "URL to access the SharePoint file" to point to the right URL to have file attached to email, pls.

@GuilhermeProvenzanoZimmerman : I've found a better solution, so I've edited my answer

Hello, @Farkas János. Super thanks for your guidance and kindness.
I've followed your steps, but I get this error when on the step "Get File Metadata Using Path":
"File not found
clientRequestId: 81630113-ddf7-4a14-96f9-a3532f4604cf
serviceRequestId: 844639a1-e041-9000-6761-014e2f362dd0"
If it would help, the URL in MS Lists look like that below:
https://transfermateltd.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/MXNGlobalAccounts/ARbwW-jIrbGOvj6_-zuO3wQCgcA5lLUk_17mb6tLWMzpeE
NOTE: MXNGlobalAccounts is the SharePoint Group Folder (site) which the files are stored related to this process.

@GuilhermeProvenzanoZimmerman, this /:x/:s ... part looks like not the original url, but the one you get when you select "copy url" from some action menu. Your files have a cleaner url. See it in this article: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/06/sharepoint-online-get-direct-link-to-document.html
